# App Crash in lower version than android 5 Read Description

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-appcompat, classnotfoundexception

My App continue crash if i run my app lower then android version 5, i don't know why?
This is my error which i found currently, it say no resource found like this,

**android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02006e**

but it is in my R.java file of project.check below...

[image: R File Image]

This is my build.gradle configration:-
[image: gradle image]

Please if you know how to solve this problem then please tell me as soon as possible.

Thank You.

Comment: clean the project and run. Make sure you have that id in xml

Comment: Remove instant run and try again.

Comment: Thanks Kalai.G and sukumar, but this is not the solution for me. Because i already clean my project three or more time's and remove instant run from the starting of my project.

Answer (score 0):

**The Correct solution of this problem for me is:**

i used an ***image ic_menu_send*** from ***drawable-v21*** folder of my project, that's the reason when i run my app on ***Android version 5+*** devices it works fine.

But when i run app on lower version then lollipop it can not find the ***drawable-v21 folder*** resources, so app going to crash continue.

I just remove this image from my ***ImageView android:src*** and set another image instead of this, now my works fine on all devices.

According to me now,If you are using Android Studio 2+ version, then i think you should keep in mind these type of issue before using SDK drawable folders images.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your target sdk version.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "appcode.infotech"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 16
    multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: i try your solution, but it not works.. check my answer bro... That's the main reason why this problem occur and how can i solved my problem.. Thanks for your attention and reply

Comment: your minimum and target sdk should be 16